# deferred execution or not

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Are below comments correct about DEFERRED EXECUTION?

```
1. var x = dc.myTables.Select(r=>r);//yes
2. var x = dc.myTables.Where(..).Select(r=>new {..});//yes
3. var x = dc.myTables.Where(..).Select(r=>new MyCustomClass {..});//no
```

In other words, I always thought projecting custom class objects will always cause eager execution. But I couldn't find references supporting/denying it (though I am seeing results contradicting it, hence the post)

Comment: All 3 executes deferred.

Comment: You need to expand upon this:  _though I am seeing results contradicting it_

Comment: Could this behaviour depend on the nature of the `MyCustomClass` constructor?

Comment: @AustinSalonen - I meant, 'I am seeing results contradicting my assumption'. I try to use x in 3. later, but getting exceptions saying dc is already disposed

Comment: Post a code snippet where that's true of #3 but not true of #1 and #2.

Comment: @AustinSalonen - I meant I am seeing results contradicting my assumption that 'projecting custom class objects will cause eager execution'. Guess I wasn't clear.

Comment: How are you confirming that?

Comment: @AustinSalonen - Suppose I had say stmt1 - IEnumerable<> x, stmnt2. using(dc){ x= project customclassobjects} stmnt3. access x             stmnt3 throwing exception because dc is disposed already, so it implies not eager execution.

Comment: All you've proven is that `using` works as expected.  To show _not eager_, your mapping (Select) needs to do something you can observe (say write to the console) and assert that nothing was "done".  For example, `r => { Console.WriteLine("qqqxxx"); return new MyCustomClass(...); }`  (though linq-to-sql may not like this...)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26262/discussion-between-brian-and-austin-salonen)

Comment: Can't chat from my office...

Comment: @AustinSalonen - 
I guess I expected (if eager execution,), x would persist still, outside the using{}

Comment: Nope.  The using translates to `try { x = ...; }finally {x.Dispose();}`.  Given how you defined it, `x` will be in scope outside of the using but with it set in the `using` it will be disposed when you use it later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every statement in your question is an example of deferred execution.  The contents of the `Select` and `Where` statement have no effect on whether or not the resulting value is deferred executed or not.  The `Select` + `Where` statements themselves dictate that.

As a counter example consider the `Sum` method.  This is always eagerly executed irrespective of what the input is.

```
var sum = dc.myTables.Sum(...);  // Always eager
```

Answer (score 3):

To prove your point, your test should look like this:

```
var tracer = string.Empty;
Func<inType, outType> map = r => {
       tracer = "set";
       return new outType(...);
    } 

var x = dc.myTables.Where(..).Select(map);

// this confirms x was never enumerated as tracer would be "set".
Assert.AreEqual(string.Empty, tracer);
// confirm that it would have enumerated if it could
CollectionAssert.IsNotEmpty(x);
```

Comment: You can even have the iterator throw an exception when first iterated, making it very clear exactly when the first item is actually requested from it.

Answer (score 2):

It has been my observation that the only way to force execution right away is to force iteration of the collection.  I do this by calling `.ToArray()` on my LINQ.

Comment: ToArray? ToList is better.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer That would depend on what you intend on doing with the results.  The implementations of the two functions are pretty much the same so I doubt there is any performance hit.  In my case I cannot think of examples where I'd want to use LINQ to create a list that I'd want to add items to afterwards.

Comment: @MalcolmO'Hare No performance issues. Arrays _as is_ have limited use cases, while lists and collections in general terms are the recommended objects to store objects in OOP and specially in .NET/C#.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer:  _general terms are the recommended objects to store objects in OOP and specially in .NET/C#_ -- [citation needed]

Comment: @AustinSalonen I'm not going to elaborate on this in a comment. Just _google_ this topic and you'll find a lot of info. In addition, StackOverflow has many Q&A about this. Just do a search :D

Answer (score 2):

Generally methods that return a sequence use deferred execution:

```
IEnumerable<X> ---> Select ---> IEnumerable<Y>
```

and methods that return a single object doesn't:

```
IEnumerable<X> ---> First ---> Y
```

So, methods like `Where`, `Select`, `Take`, `Skip`, `GroupBy` and `OrderBy` use deferred execution because they can, while methods like `First`, `Single`, `ToList` and `ToArray` doesn't because they can't.

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894490/linq-what-is-the-quickest-way-to-find-out-deferred-execution-or-not)

Comment: It's a good deduction, while it's not absolutely necessary that you return a sequence in order to do _deferred execution_. But yes, in .NET BCL this is true!

Comment: Well, having deferred execution isn't just a boolean yes/no.  It's more complex than that.  For example, `Where` doesn't invoke the predicate on each item until the last possible moment, right before that item is requested by the iterator, whereas `GroupBy` or `OrderBy` on the other hand will need to eagerly process the entire result set as soon as the first item is requested, so they can only defer execution from the time the query is created until the first iteration.  Then there are cases like `Intersect` that eagerly evaluate only one sequence when the first item is requested.

Answer (score 2):

`.Select(...)` is always deferred.

When you're working with `IQueryable<T>`, this and other deferred execution methods build up an expression tree and this isn't ever compiled into an actual executable expression until it's iterated. That is, you need to:

- Do a for-each on the projected enumerable.
- Call a method that internally enumerates the enumerable *(i.e. `.Any(...)`, `.Count(...)`, `.ToList(...)`, ...).*

Comment: `isn't ever compiled into an actual executable expression until it's iterated. That is, you need to:` that only applies to the `IQueryable` overload.  For the `IEnumerable` overload it's compiled into executable code at compile time, not at runtime.  It's a delegate that simply isn't called until iteration.

Comment: @Servy Are you meaning that Select on IEnumerable isn't part of an expression tree?

Comment: That is correct.  The IEnumerable select takes a `Func<TSource, TResult`, the IQueryable takes an `Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>>`.  As similar as they look, they are very different.

Comment: @Servy But, after checking the tags on the question, I feel that the answer is still correct: it's for linq-to-sql (IQueryable). By the way, I don't know why, I thought `Select(...)` was expression in any situation (it could be as simple as looking at `IEnumerable<T>` `Select(...)` overloads...