# Xamarin - Sqlite.net memory consumption is very high

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android, sqlite.net

I am working on Xamarin.Android application. In this application, I have local database. I am using sqlite.net plugin to manage sqlite operations.

While testing application on lower configuration, I found have memory consumption from application. while checking with Xamarin Profiler, I got to know that majority memory is allocated to one of database method [more than 50 %].

It is used in `System.Linq.Enumerable:FirstofDefault<SQlite.TableMapping/Column>`.

Can we manually deallocate this memory? is there any way? Can we release memory from application progrmattically?

I have tried with `GC.Collect()` but it is not useful.

If anyone have idea actual reason behind this issue?

Comment: Generally methods that return a sequence use deferred execution  .Here is a similar issue that maybe can help you .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875875/entity-framework-linq-functions-and-memory-usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, i found that we can use `PRAGMA`function to release memory.

We can call below query to release memory manually.

```
PRAGMA shrink_memory;
```