# IEnumerable<T> and .Where Linq method behaviour?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I thought I know everything about `IEnumerable<T>` but I just met a case that I cannot explain. When we call .Where linq method on a `IEnumerable`, the execution is deferred until the object is enumerated, isn't it?

So how to explain the sample below :

```
public class CTest
{
    public CTest(int amount)
    {
        Amount = amount;
    }

    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Amount:{Amount}";
    }

    public static IEnumerable<CTest> GenerateEnumerableTest()
    {
        var tab = new List<int> { 2, 5, 10, 12 };

        return tab.Select(t => new CTest(t));
    }
}
```

Nothing bad so far!
But the following test gives me an unexpected result although my knowledge regarding `IEnumerable<T>` and `.Where` linq method :

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestCSharp()
{
    var tab = CTest.GenerateEnumerableTest();

    foreach (var item in tab.Where(i => i.Amount > 6))
    {
        item.Amount = item.Amount * 2;
    }

    foreach (var t in tab)
    {
        var s = t.ToString();
        Debug.Print(s);
    }
}
```

No item from tab will be multiplied by 2. The output will be :
Amount:2
Amount:5
Amount:10
Amount:12

Does anyone can explain why after enumerating tab, I get the original value.
**Of course, everything work fine after calling `.ToList()` just after calling `GenerateEnumerableTest()` method.**

Comment: Short version: each time you call `GenerateEnumerableTest` you generate different reference objects.

Comment: `return tab.Select(t => new CTest(t)).ToList(); ` or `var tab = CTest.GenerateEnumerableTest().ToList()` should fix

Comment: What gunr said. I'm too sleepy to write a coherent answer :-(

Answer (score 9):

```
var tab = CTest.GenerateEnumerableTest();
```

This `tab` is a LINQ query that generates `CTest` instances that are initialized from `int`-values which come from an integer array which will never change. So whenever you ask for this query you will get the "same" instances(with the original `Amount`).

If you want to "materialize" this query you could use `ToList` and then change them.
Otherwise you are modifying `CTest` instances that exist only in the first `foreach` loop. The second loop enumerates other `CTest` instances with the unmodified `Amount`.

So the query contains the informations how to get the items, you could also call the method directly:

```
foreach (var item in CTest.GenerateEnumerableTest().Where(i => i.Amount > 6))
{
    item.Amount = item.Amount * 2;
}

foreach (var t in CTest.GenerateEnumerableTest())
{
   // now you don't expect them to be changed, do you?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like many LINQ operations, [`Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3894544/2946329) is lazy and use deferred execution so your lambda expression is never being executed, because you're calling `Select` but never using the results. This is why, everything work fine after calling `.ToList()` just after calling `GenerateEnumerableTest()` method:

```
var tab = CTest.GenerateEnumerableTest().ToList();
```

Comment: Sure, the result is used in the `foreach` loops. But each loop will use the query again to request the items from GenerateEnumerableTest.